# Need help on opening Interactive Trader Workstation

Tags: java, ios, macos, interactive-brokers, tws

When I try to open Trader Workstation on Mac OS, there is a startup error.

- How do I resolve this?
- What does this error message mean?

The error message:

```java
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input byte[] should at least have 2 bytes for base64 bytes
        at java.util.Base64$Decoder.outLength(Base64.java:659)
        at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:525)
        at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:549)
        at twslaunch.jauthentication.aV.d(aV.java:210)
        at twslaunch.jauthentication.aV.c(aV.java:183)
        at twslaunch.jclient.login.l.a(l.java:528)
        at java.util.Hashtable.forEach(Hashtable.java:879)
        at twslaunch.jclient.login.l.a(l.java:528)
        at twslaunch.jclient.login.l.a(l.java:408)
        at jclient.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:189)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:85)
        at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.MacLauncher.main(MacLauncher.java:52)
```

Comment: I've been using Mac OS with Trader Workstation for years and don't have that problem on my computer.  Which Mac OS are you using and which version of Trader Workstation are you using?

Comment: I updated my mac os to catalina and Trader Workstation is the latest version. It was working fine in the first two days, but then it start showing this error message. I tried deleting it and re-installing TWS, but it kept showing this error message.

Comment: I suggest contacting Interactive Brokers for TWS tech support.